# Word Embeddings with neural networks in keras

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, word-embedding

Can someone give me an intuitive explanation for why we use word embeddings and how neural networks make this process easier and better?

Comment: Too broad for SO, I think, and not really programming-based.

Answer (score 2):

Word embedding is the collective name for a set of language modeling and feature learning techniques in natural language processing (NLP) where words or phrases from the vocabulary are mapped to vectors of real numbers.

There are many branches and many research groups working on word embeddings. In 2013, a team at Google led by Tomas Mikolov created `word2vec`, a word embedding toolkit which can train vector space models faster than the previous approaches.Most new word embedding techniques rely on a neural network architecture instead of more traditional n-gram models and unsupervised learning.

Why do newer methods rely on neural networks? Mostly because they can solve the problem faster and more efficiently. Part of the reason for this is  neural architectures take the whole sorted sequence into account, and not each word in isolation.

For a more detailed explanation, you probably want to do some research. Reading [this](https://medium.com/@josecamachocollados/on-the-contribution-of-neural-networks-and-word-embeddings-in-natural-language-processing-c8bb1b85c61c) blog post might be a good start.